# RANDOM 0, 1, -1 IN VERILOG

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I would like to generate random decimal number 0, 1 or -1 in verilog, that I can add it to my basic signal and get some noise on it with it. 
I tried with

```
reg [1:0] SIGNAL_noise_ii;
SIGNAL_noise_ii <= {$random}%2;
```

but it doesnt work the way I want.

Could someone give me advice what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
reg signed [1:0] SIGNAL_noise_ii;
SIGNAL_noise_ii <= $signed($urandom_range(0,2))-1;
```

If `SIGNAL_noise_ii` is required to represent a "random decimal number 0, 1 or -1", it would seem a good idea to make it `signed`.

`$urandom_range(min,max)` generates a random *unsigned* integer in the range `min` to `max` inclusive.

So, let's used `$signed` to make that integer signed and then let's subtract 1 from it. *Literals* with no base (such as `1`) are signed in Verilog by default. We need to make everything on the right hand side of the assignment *signed*, because if mix signed and unsigned quantities in Veriog, *unsigned* arithmetic is done.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3tCK

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution in SystemVerilog is to use the randomize() method constraining the variable to the set of values you want.

```
bit signed [1:0] SIGNAL_noise_ii;
...
randomize(SIGNAL_noise_ii) with {SIGNAL_noise_ii inside {-1,0,1};};
// alternatively specify a distribution 
randomize(SIGNAL_noise_ii) with {SIGNAL_noise_ii dist  {-1:=25,0:=50,1:=25};};
```